# The tangent space of the boundary of a manifold with boundary is a subspace of the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I was trying to understand the following sentence in some notes I am reading:

Let $M$ be a manifold with boundary.

*At any point $p \in {\partial}M$ there is a canonical subspace $T_{p}({\partial}M) \subset T_{p}(M)$; the quotient space is the a real line $\nu_{p}$.*

I know of $T_{p}(M)$ as the vector space consisting of operators or derivations $\nu: F(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $F(M)$ is the algebra of smooth functions from $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Does this natural subspace involve some sort of imbedding of a $F({\partial}M)$ into $F(M)$?

I apologize if this question is obvious.

Comment: There is a natural map $\rho: F(M) \rightarrow F(\partial M)$ (restriction).  This induces a map $Der_p(\partial M) \rightarrow Der_p(M), \delta \mapsto \delta \circ \rho$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it involves projecting $F(M)\to F(\partial M)$, i.e. observing that a smooth function on $M$ restricts to a smooth function on $\partial M$. This *seems* to go the wrong directions, but now the derivations come into play: a derivation $ F(\partial M)\to\mathbb R$ gives rise to a map $F(M)\to F(\partial M)\to\mathbb R$ (that is also a derivation, as you may check).

Comment: Thanks, I understand, if we have a smooth function $f$ from M to $\mathbb{R}$, we can restrict that map to ${\partial}M$. This allows us to send a derivation in the tangent space of the boundary to a derivation in the tangent space of the manifold, using the composite mentioned in your answer and the comment above. Thanks a lot. That helps.

Comment: Hello! I have a problem about your answer- how to know this correspondence is injective? Formally, let i be this map, $X_p$ be tangent vector at $p$ on manifold $∂M$, if $i(X_p)=0$, i.e  $i(X_p)f=0$ where f is smooth function on $M$,can we have $X_p=0$?